# loop through posts and display inserted media and post title as a link

Tags: loop, urls, attachments

I'm fiddling around with an issue I cannot solve. Inside the loop I would like to find the URL of an inserted media file (pdf, doc etc) and display this as an anchor. Furthermore I would like to display the title of the current post as content of the link. My attempt so far:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
     <a href="<?php wp_get_attachment_url(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

displaying the title works totally fine. But the `href=""` does not show up anything. Thanks

Note: It is a media file simply inserted as post content, not a featured image or something.

Comment: Is it not working with this solution? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163795

Comment: @Roberthue it isn't :( and I didnt want to continue asking at all.

Comment: Okay, then I will let someone else help you with this. :)

Comment: @Roberthue mate I tried the above code (this post) on a fresh install. And it does not work, but this is exactly what I want.

Comment: No it will not work. First `wp_get_attachment_url()` need the ID of the attachment to output URL which you are not providing and simply adding `$id` or `$post->id` will not work either because that will be post IDs, not the ID of the attachment(s). You will need a way to find all the attachments of a post & their IDs and then use each IDs in `wp_get_attachment_url()` to get URL.

Comment: @Roberthue so what will be the most simple way of this, so there will be a post with 1 file each. And I want the file link and the post title of each post in my page.

Comment: I already posted the [solution here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163795) but somehow it's not working for you. That's why I will let someone else answer this. But the main idea will be the same as I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: @Roberthue it does work, but displays always the same title and id. It seems that it does not loop through the posts, but through the attachments

Comment: I am sure it's some issue with theme or plugin. Have you tried disabling all plugins? I can look into your theme if you can upload your complete theme as a zip somewhere.

Comment: @Roberthue it is not. Please have a look at the edit2 of my other question.

Comment: How exactly the "right" attachment for a post should be selected, what is your logic for it?

Comment: @Rarst no logic since each post will only have 1 attachment!

Comment: This _is_ logic. :) Now define "have". Inserted into the post body? Set as featured image? Just uploaded with post as parent?

Comment: @Rarst Yes inserted to the post body. Without any additional content, just 1 file by media library selection,

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick peek at the [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163795) referenced in other comments, and the gist of how you loop through attachments there meshes with what is shown in the [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image#Examples) documentation example.  In a nutshell, any attachments on a particular post will reference that post by ID.

In particular, it's crucial to understand that attachments are also posts themselves of the post type **attachment**.  Inside your main loop, you'll get your attachments by running a nested query for all attachments whose post parent is equal to the ID of your outer loop's post:

```
// Our main (outer) query:
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();

    $nested_query = new WP_Query(array(
        "post_type" => "attachment",
        "post_status" => "inherit",
        "posts_per_page" => -1,
        "post_parent" => get_the_ID()  // attachments belonging to the post we're looking at
    ));
    $attachments = $nested_query->get_posts();  // get an array of post objects for each attachment
    foreach($attachments as $att_post) {
        printf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", wp_get_attachment_url($att_post->ID), get_the_title());
    }
}
```

I doubt the above does what you want it to, primarily because I don't think you want to echo an anchor for every single attachment that has the post title for its text.  However, for illustrative purposes, this is how you could loop through attachments nested within a post loop.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So basically what I want to achieve is: All posts that I have on my Wordpress have 1 file inserted, and I simply want to put out each post as an `<a>` with the title of the post, and an href="" to the media inserted in posts body. Nothing else

Comment: You could adjust that nested loop to only pull one post per page instead of all.  This only works if you ever have one attachment, though (and this includes featured image if you have one), so if you start getting the wrong attachment you'll want to rethink this strategy.